# Find the best dimensions of a tent with horizontal ridge pole. Assume the two ends closed by isosceles triangles. There is no floor.

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Find the best dimensions of a tent with horizontal ridge pole. Assume the two ends closed by isosceles triangles. There is no floor.

The total surface area of the tent is
\begin{align*}
  A & =  2 \times \text{Area of the rectangular sides} + 2 \times \text{Area of the isosceles triangles at the ends}.
\end{align*}
Let $x$ and $y$ be the sides of the rectangular canvas and $\theta$ be the angle made by the isosceles triangle. Then the area of the tent is
\begin{align*}
  A & = 2xy+2 \times \frac{x^{2}}{2}\sin \theta = 2xy+x^{2}\sin \theta.
\end{align*}
For the minimum of $A$, we have the necessary conditions $\displaystyle \frac{\partial A}{\partial x}=0$, $\displaystyle \frac{\partial A}{\partial y}=0$  and $\displaystyle \frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta}=0$. Therefore, differentiating $f$ with respect to $x$, $y$ and $\theta$, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial A}{\partial x} & = 2y+2x \sin \theta, \quad \frac{\partial A}{\partial y} = 2y \quad \text{ and } \quad \frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta} = 2x\cos \theta.
\end{align*}

Is the formulation correct? If not please provide the correct formulation. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by a "tent with no floor" ? That the two sides of the roof reach the ground ?

Comment: No floor means - no canvas is used for the floor.

Comment: The first sentence "find the best dimensions..." doesn't give all the information ! Do you want to minimize the total canvas area for a given volume ? But here you don't mention the volume ?....

Comment: Please say if the question of your homework mentions the **volume** of the tent. This should be the case. Because if you want to minimize the area, take it at once to be equal to zero...

Comment: I have got the problem from Advanced Calculus, Widder. As you said it should be with minimum surface area for the given volume.

Comment: Then 1) compute the volume $V$ as a function of $x$,$y$ and $\theta$. 2) Form the system $\partial V/\partial x=0$,  $\partial V/\partial y=0$,  $\partial V/\partial \theta=0$ 3) Solve it.